# Restart a Grails app programmatically

Tags: linux, grails, groovy

I'm attempting to restart an app using the code below (it backs a restart button). However the restart doesn't occur.

```
def process = "sleep 5s && sudo service $appname restart".execute()
process.waitForOrKill(2000)
System.exit(0)
```

Some relevant details:

- Got the basic idea from [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java)
- The command in quotes works from the
  commandline without error. Note that the app is started using a
  service wrapper
- Logging confirms that $appname correctly resolves to
  the service
- The reason for the sleep it so that we don’t attempt to
  restart while the app is running
- If I drop the System.exit statement, the restart still doesn't happen
- ‘waitForOrKill’ is an alternative to options
  that would require that the app wait for the process to complete,
  which doesn’t make sense since the process restarts the app. It's telling the app restart process to fail after 2 seconds
- sudo config: NOPASSWD was
  added for the chadmin account, which is the account running the app.
  It’s only added for the service command.
- Additional Linux logging might help...not an area I'm familiar with. No problems show up in syslog

Comment: Are you wanting to do this to a process started with run-app or to a deployed app?

Comment: To a deployed app. We're using a fat jar (created by standalone app runner) with a service wrapper. Incidentally I found out that a killed app starts back up, possibly due to the service wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and the key was to make sure that the waitForOrKill setting is large enough for the process to complete. Seems obvious in hindsight.